# How to backup all installed software/packages on AIX?

Tags: aix

Are there any ways to backup all the packages on an AIX 6.1 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a way which allows you to restore them.  The normal way to backup AIX is to run a `mksysb`.  You can then recover / install / build from the resulting file (via tape, DVD, network, etc.)

Is there something specific you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit ambiguous. Do you only mean a list of all [lpp,rpm,emgr] packages, or the contents of those packages? For the former case, that is quite easy to achieve but not really useful.

For the latter case, if all the packages only contain files that are located within the rootvg and not within directories excluded from mksysb, then an mksysb would be the way to back them up.
If not, then you probably need to create your own backup mechanism - but how useful is it to only backup all your packages without having a full bare-metal backup of your machines?

Maybe you should elaborate a bit on the use-case.